# Program continues to execute after exit

Tags: python

After reading in an ip address from the user I want to exit out if not valid.  It seems to continue executing the code in the function before exiting.  I would like it to exit immediately.  I have even tried using quit() and exit() in the expection but all had the same result.

Function:

```py
def f_validate_args(test_args):
 try:
  socket.inet_aton(test_args.server)
 except socket.error as SE:
  raise SystemExit(SE)

 print 'Everything is OK!'
```

Main:

```py
validation = f_validate_args(io_args)

print(io_args)
```

Running program with an Invalid IP:

```
Everything is OK
illegal IP address string passed to inet_aton
```

Running program with a Valid IP:

```
Everything is OK!
Namespace(...)
```

Comment: My crystal ball thinks that there is an indentation problem in your real program.

Comment: Thats what I thought as well... but I checked and rewrite multiple times with the same result *EDIT:  Your crystal ball is correct.  I went back to the code and infact the indentation was the issue...DOH!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When an invalid IP is provided, the function will raise an OSError. So you will need to catch it with

```
def f_validate_args(test_args):
 try:
  socket.inet_aton(test_args.server)
 except OSError:
  # your error handling here
 except socket.error as SE:
  raise SystemExit(SE)

 print 'Everything is OK!'
```

Source: https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.inet_aton

Answer (score 0):

You can try `os.system` package, to kill from bash:

```py
import os

def f_validate_args(test_args):
 try:
  socket.inet_aton(test_args.server)
 except socket.error as SE:
  os.system('pkill your_program_name')
  raise SystemExit(SE)
```

Answer (score 0):

There may be resources (socket related) that prevent the program to exit cleanly.

Maybe dirty but sure to work: call `os._exit`. It calls low-level `exit` without using the exception mechanism that `sys.exit` uses.

```
def f_validate_args(test_args):
 try:
  socket.inet_aton(test_args.server)
 except socket.error as SE:
  print(str(SE))
  os._exit(1)

 print('Everything is OK!')
```

Of course, python doesn't have a chance to exit gracefully. Do this only if you can't do otherwise.